# How to include the initial range value in this list of dates that I get from an iterable?

Tags: javascript, iterator, iterable

I try to make the range object an iterable in order to get the dates between the range limits. both dates included

```js
let range = {
  from: new Date("2020-01-01"),
  to: new Date("2020-01-10"),
};

range[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
  return {
    current: this.from,
    last: this.to,
    next() {
      if (this.current.getTime() < this.last.getTime()) {
        return {
          done: false,
          value: new Date(this.current.setDate(this.current.getDate() + 1)),
        };
      }

      return { done: true };
    },
  };
};

for (const iterator of range) {
  console.log(iterator);
}

console.log(Array.from(range));
```

What I try to do but without success is that the starting date of the range is included in the date list, in this case 2020-01-01

About `for..of`

Current result

```
2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-04T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-05T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z
```

Expected result

```
2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z <-- initial value
2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-04T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-05T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z
2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z
```

About `Array.from`

Current result

```
[]
```

Expected result

```
[2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z..., 2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z]
```

Another question I have is the reason why when using `Array.from(range)` I hope to get the array with the dates between the range, but it returns an empty array

**Update 0**

This is the same exercise only with integers and using `for..of` and `Array.from` I get the expected result

https://jsfiddle.net/atd94h0L/

Comment: you set + 1 for the date on the first iteration

Comment: sorry, the iterator has already reached the end when you use Array.from.  you need to be using new objects or a wrapped iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to include the initial range value in this list of dates that I get from an iterable?

Yield the initial value, not the updated current value.

> Why when using `Array.from(range)` it returns an empty array?

Because your code does modify the `range.from` date object. After you looped through the range, it is exhausted, and `range.from` (`== range.current`) is `>=`range.to`.

So to fix both issues:

```js
let range = {
  from: new Date("2020-01-01"),
  to: new Date("2020-01-10"),
};

range[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
  return {
    current: this.from,
    last: this.to,
    next() {
      const cur = this.current;
      if (cur < this.last) {
        this.current = new Date(cur);
//                     ^^^^^^^^
        this.current.setDate(cur.getDate() + 1)
        return {
          done: false,
          value: cur,
        };
      }

      return { done: true };
    },
  };
};

for (const iterator of range) {
  console.log(iterator);
}

console.log(Array.from(range));
```